# Mime check error in angular and nodejs app

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, mean

I am developing a angular and nodejs. I am using scss for my styling. I am getting the following error:
[image]

Can somebody help me out? It is working fine in localhost but not in azure we app.

I have created a new app with css as styling language and still getting this error?

[image]

Here is my index.html before build

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ui</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-redirect></app-redirect>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.html in dist/ui folder after build

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ui</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<style>html,body{height:100%}body{margin:0;font-family:Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif}body{background-image:linear-gradient(white 50%,#DD2637 50%,180deg);background-attachment:fixed;vertical-align:middle}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.6f21374a26c18d55.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.6f21374a26c18d55.css"></noscript></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-redirect></app-redirect>
<script src="runtime.7cb62255c16cf7ce.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.5822e5466085ff0d.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.eef2d5096fccdf04.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

I am using the following line to serve angular ui has part of nodejs server:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname,'dist/ui/')))
```

Comment: There is no need to type "./public" if your url has "./" typing in the beginning and also add this to public/index.html: <base href="/" />

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu it is already added.